# Can C++ deduce argument type from default value?

Tags: c++, templates, default, template-argument-deduction, default-arguments

I tried to write this function with a default template argument:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void func(int i1, int i2, A a, B b = 123){
    ...
}
```

In my mind I can call it like this: `func(1, 2, 3)` and compiler should deduce type `B` as `int` from default value, but I get `no instance of overloaded function`.
Is it incorrect C++ construction and compiler can't deduce type in this case?

Comment: What do you suppose, for example, `func<int, float>(1,2,3)` should do?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel equivalent to call func<int, float>(1,2,3,123)

Comment: Come on, templates are dead, just use `void func(int i1, int i2, auto a, auto b = 123)`.

Comment: @Vorac Same issue: `func(1, 2, 3)` fails since `b`'s type can't be deduced.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The type of a template parameter in a function can't be deduced from a default argument. As shown in the example on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type):

> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function
> default argument:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> void f(T = 5, T = 7); 
>
> void g()
> {
>     f(1);     // OK: calls f<int>(1, 7)
>     f();      // error: cannot deduce T
>     f<int>(); // OK: calls f<int>(5, 7)
> }
> ```

However, you can specify a default argument for the template parameter:

```
template<typename A, typename B = int>
void func(int i1, int i2, A a, B b = 123){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, this change also allows deduction with `func(1,2, 3, {});`

Comment: @Deduplicator Braced-init-list belongs to non-deduced context, so deduction doesn't occur, the default argument `int` is used instead. Then `{}` is passed as argument, parameter `b` with type `int` is initialized with value `0`.

Comment: I know, just wanted to add that this invocation works thereafter too.

Answer (score 12):

As often when default arguments don't work you can use overloads:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void func(int i1, int i2, A a, B b){
    ...
}
template<typename A>
void func(int i1, int i2, A a){
    func(i1,i2,a,123);
}
```