# How to assign a default argument to a concept input parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, auto, c++-concepts, default-arguments

I'm trying to assign a default value to a "concept" input parameter:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::integral auto num = 1)
{
    std::cout << "Num: " << num << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(7);
    foo(true);
    foo('&');
    //foo();  // Does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

But I get a compilation error when the argument is omitted:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo()’
   14 |     foo();  // Does not compile
      |     ~~~^~
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: ‘template  requires  integral void foo(auto:11)’
    4 | void foo(std::integral auto num = 1)
      |      ^~~
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:14:8: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘auto:11’
   14 |     foo();  // Does not compile
      |     ~~~^~
```

If assigning a default argument to a concept is not possible,
then I find it strange that the program compiles when I call 'foo' *with* arguments, but not without.

What am I doing wrong?

I can replace `foo()` with `foo<int>()` and it'll work, but I shouldn't have to do that.

I can also replace the definition of 'foo' with:

```
template<typename T = int> requires std::integral<T>
void foo(T num = 1)
```

And it'll once again work, but I shouldn't have to be that explicit.

Comment: This is not specific to concepts or abbreviated function templates. `template <typename T> void foo(T num = 1)` doesn't work either, but I'm not sure why it's  not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of template parameters in functions [cannot be deduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156721/can-c-deduce-argument-type-from-default-value) from default arguments, and there is no rule change for the concept. In this case, you still need to provide the default type for the template parameter

```
template<std::integral T = int>
void foo(T num = 1)
{
  std::cout << "Num: " << num << std::endl;
}
```